# I am trying to implement sliding imageview in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

So I am trying to implement a sliding imageview. I dont need it to be fullscreen. Just some part of the upper screen. So I have out an imageview in the activity like this -

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Now android:src is an drawable I created for example. So is it possible that I can create an array of images and give that array name as the source value? If yes then how can I make the images show on after another? 
I dont want thumbnails to be displayed. As soon as the activity starts the images should start showing up just like you would see on a website normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a [**ViewPager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) , and for each fragment of its [**FragmentPagerAdapter**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) set it to have a layout that includes the imageView and show the correct image based on its location.

note that if the images are too large, you should downsample them before showing them.

also note that you should hard reference to the bitmaps in the fragments and also store the fragments, as it will use more and more memory, the more fragments you have.

in general, you should at least allow the app to have reference to 3 images, since the user should be allowed to go right and left from the current fragment.